# parameter marker not allowed (updating Access database)

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

```
Statement st = connect.createStatement();
String sql = "update StudentDatabaseS set RollNo = ?, FullName = ?, FatherName = ?, FatherCNIC = ?, DateOfBirth = ?, Class = ?, Address = ?, City = ?, Province = ? where RollNo = '"+Srollno+"'";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

ps = connect.prepareStatement(sql);

ps.setInt(1, roll_mo);
ps.setString(2, name_mo);
ps.setString(3, Fname_mo);
ps.setString(4, fcnic_mo);
ps.setString(5, dob_mo);
ps.setInt   (6, Class_mo);
ps.setString(7, add_mo);
ps.setString(8, city_mo);
ps.setString(9, prvnce_mo);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

I am trying to update a record in an Access database and it is continuously throwing me exceptions, for example parameter markers not allowed.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please provide the exception stack trace, and the value of `Srollno` (and you might want to consider using a parameter for that as well!)

Comment: ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql); seems to be useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When

```java
String sql = "update StudentDatabaseS set RollNo = ?, FullName = ?, FatherName = ?, FatherCNIC = ?, DateOfBirth = ?, Class = ?, Address = ?, City = ?, Province = ? where RollNo = '"+Srollno+"'";
```

the line

```java
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
```

makes no sense because

1. that query does not return a ResultSet, and
2. `executeQuery` has no way of knowing what values correspond to the parameter placeholders (`?`).

If you omit that line then the "parameter marker not allowed" error will go away and you can carry on with your UPDATE using the PreparedStatement.

Comment: bro i have omitted the result set line but now its throwing me null pointer exception for the code above

Comment: i have posted the answer below thumbs up for you !

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
         Statement st = connect.createStatement();
         String sql = "update StudentDatabaseS set RollNo = ?, FullName = ?, FatherName = ?, FatherCNIC = ?, DateOfBirth = ?, Class = ?, Address = ?, City = ?, Province = ? where RollNo = '"+Srollno+"'";
         try {
        ps = connect.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setInt(1, roll_mo);
        ps.setString(2, name_mo);
        ps.setString(3, Fname_mo);
        ps.setString(4, fcnic_mo);
        ps.setString(5, dob_mo);
        ps.setInt   (6, Class_mo);
        ps.setString(7, add_mo);
        ps.setString(8, city_mo);
        ps.setString(9, prvnce_mo);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Modified !");
        search_input.requestFocus();
         }

         catch(Exception ex)
         {
               ex.printStackTrace();
         }

    }

         catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```